# Crawler can't connect to MySQL database under heavy load

Tags: python, mysql, web-crawler

I have a crawler written in Python, which can't connect to the database after crawling for a while. Sometimes it works for 10 minutes, after which the following error log appears:

```
(2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10055)")
(2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10055)")
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\eclipse\workspace\Crawler\src\Crawlers\Zanox.py", line 73, in <module>
c.main()
File "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\eclipse\workspace\Crawler\src\Crawlers\Zanox.py", line 38, in main
self.getInfo()
File "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\eclipse\workspace\Crawler\src\Crawlers\Zanox.py", line 69, in getInfo
comparator.main()
File "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\eclipse\workspace\Crawler\src\CrawlerHelpScripts\Comparator.py", line 23, in main
self.compare()
File "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\eclipse\workspace\Crawler\src\CrawlerHelpScripts\Comparator.py", line 36, in compare
deliveryInfo = self.db.getDeliveryInfo() 
File "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\eclipse\workspace\Crawler\src\Database\dell.py", line 29, in getDeliveryInfo
result = self.db.select(com, vals)
File "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\eclipse\workspace\Crawler\src\Database\Database.py", line 24, in select
self.con.close()
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: closing a closed connection
```

So at a certain point it just can't connect to the database, running on localhost, and afterwards produces a ProgrammingError. Handling this exception is not the problem, because it will keep running but also will keep producing the Can't connect Error.

Here is the code I use for inserting/selecting in my database:

```
def select(self, com, vals):
    try:
        self.con = mdb.connect(self.host, self.user, self.password, self.database)
        cur = self.con.cursor()
        cur.execute(com,vals)

        ver = cur.fetchall()
        return ver
    except  mdb.Error as e:
        print e
    finally:
        if self.con:
            self.con.close()

def insert(self, com, vals):
    try:
        self.con = mdb.connect(self.host, self.user, self.password, self.database)
        cur = self.con.cursor()
        cur.execute(com, vals)
        self.con.commit()
    except mdb.Error as e:
        print e
    finally:
        if self.con:
            self.con.close()
```

Also, the crawler is NOT multi-threaded. Any ideas why it keeps losing connection?

EDIT: It seems that the crawler works fine untill it has inserted about 15.000 records in the database. If the table holds about 15.000 records, the crawler produces the error a lot quicker.

Comment: Why not just leave the connection open and call your queries from the same con?

Comment: I was thinking about doing so, but how exactly does this work? I have the module described in the post handling the inserting and selecting from the database, and I have a module that handles creating the querys. This last module is instantiated from another module.


Maybe this is bad design? I need to make a single module with different classes for the database querys AND inserting & selecting. However, I'd still need to instantiate it from another module. I guess I need to use a Singleton pattern for instantiating the database module if I want to leave the connection open?

Comment: I would test it for now by making the con global. If that works then change your design to use a single connection